# a tag showing image on hover with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display an image on the hover of an `a` tag which I have got complete and fully working, now I'm facing a problem...

I want the image to 'fade' in and out of the page when it is hovered rather than just appearing in order to give it a more satisfying finish.

My code at the minute is...

```
a.top-row:hover:after {
transition: .5s;
-webkit-transition: .5s;
-moz-transition: .5s;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: -295px;
left: -30px; }
```

and to display the image I have seperate id's for each of the a tags so it's done like this..

```
a#a1:hover:after {
content: url(../images/cars/audi/a1.png); }
```

HTML -

```
 <a class="top-row" id="a1">A1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? (background fixed, animating opacity)

```css
a.top-row {
  position: relative;
}

a.top-row:after {
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;  
  opacity: 0;
  content: ' ';
  pointer-events: none;
}
#a1:after {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/70x50);
}
#r8:after {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/70x50/ff00ff);
}

a.top-row:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<a class="top-row" id="a1">A1</a><br/>
<a class="top-row" id="r8">R8</a>
```

Comment: Like that yes, but the images are different depending on the id like I had #a2 which would be a different image, so on and so fourth

Comment: I added another `<a>` tag with a different hover image

Comment: Only problem I notice with this is that the height and width is what is set which means when hovering over a place which isn't the a tag but is where the picture will be, it will show. Is there anyway to counteract this method?

Comment: I added `pointer-events: none;` on the pseudo-elements and it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Having images fade-in using only CSS would only make it complicated. Instead you can use the jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() method to achieve the same.

HTML

```
<div>
<a link="" id="showme">abcd</a>
<img src="image.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="button" id="btn">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#showme').hover(
function() {
    $('#btn').fadeIn('slow');
},function() {
    $('#btn').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

CSS

```
div {
width:305px;
height:229px;
}
#btn {
display:none;
}
```